# Provide enviroment variables for production vue build

Tags: vue.js

I would like to achieve following:

1. a Vue application is build with `npm build`,
2. then the /dist result is copied to some environment
3. in this enviroment I have some static setting file with name=value settings
4. the Vue application should read this setting from local folder where it is running or default to some setting

What is the best way to do this.

Comment: use the module https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Comment: How do you run your app in production? node, nginx?

Comment: What does it mean  "Vue application should read..."? Vue app is a frontend app, you can provide env vars during build process only.

Comment: @Max Sinev: application is minimized into set of static files ... i would like to add one file of my own as the source of settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want "to inject" some settings to the bundled app so I think it can be possible only with another js file (`globalConfig.js`) with global object like:

```
window.myAppSettings = {
    MY_VARIABLE: 'some_value'
}
```

Which will be copied somehow to your dist folder on a particular environment.
You should also prepare your app to reference that file:

1. Firstly, add this settings object as external lib in `vue.config.js`

   ```
   module.exports = {
       chainWebpack: config => {
           config.externals({
               'my-app-settings': 'myAppSettings'
           })
       }
   }
   ```

   So you can get your settings in code:

   ```
    import mySettingsObject from 'my-app-settings'
    //...
    let myValue = mySettingsObject.MY_VARIABLE
   ```
2. Add reference to `globalConfig.js` in `index.html` file in the head section:

   ```
   <script src="<%= BASE_URL %>globalConfig.js"></script>
   ```

### **Local Development**

Probably you will need some default settings to be able to debug your app locally. In this case you can create `localConfig.js` in your `public` folder with some default values.
Then change your script in `index.html` to this:

```
 <script src="<%= BASE_URL %><%= VUE_APP_GLOBAL_SETTINGS_VERSION %>Settings.js"></script>
```

Then create two files in the project root `.env.local` and `.env.production`:

```
// .env.local
VUE_APP_GLOBAL_SETTINGS_VERSION=local
```

and

```
// .env.production
VUE_APP_GLOBAL_SETTINGS_VERSION=global
```

So when you run `npm run serve` it will load your local config and your app will load `localSettings.js`.
And when it builds with `npm run build` it will load `globalSettings.js` because building uses a production mode by default.

Answer (score 0):

If you created your project using `Vue CLI 3` you can do like this.

1. Make sure your settings file is named `.env` and place it in your project root.
2. In the `.env` file, your variables should be prefixed with "VUE_APP_"

   `VUE_APP_SOMEKEY=SOME_KEY_VALUE`.
3. Access them with `process.env.*`.

   `console.log(process.env.VUE_APP_SOMEKEY)  // SOME_KEY_VALUE`

Here's some more info on evironment variables in vue: [Vue CLI 3 - Environment Variables and Modes](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#using-env-variables-in-client-side-code)

**EDIT:** 
Sorry. I probably misunderstood your question. This solution will not work if your settings file is in the dist folder.

Comment: I know about this aproach ... not what I have in mind.